# React navigation 5 route undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-navigation-v5

I am trying to send some paramaters to other screen but when I console `props.route` it showing undefined. I really tried hard but not able to resolve this issue. Could someone please help me how to resolve this issue.

Thanks .

**Component 1**

```
<MaterialIcons
     name="edit"
     size={22}
     color="#646564"
     style={{ paddingRight: 7 }}
     onPress={() =>
       navigation.navigate("EducationForm", {
          editing: true,
           id: item.id,
      })
  }
/>
```

**Component 2**

```
const 2ndComponent = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  console.log('@@@@ route',route) ;    // it returns undefined
}
```

Comment: How's 2ndComponent mounted/defined in the router?

Comment: @Federkun I just edited my question , please check 2nd component define structure in router

Comment: is `EducationForm` the same as `2ndComponent`?

Comment: @Federkun Yes, I just used 2ndComponet as demo component name

Comment: can you  confirm that `navigation` is not undefined in `2ndComponent`?

Comment: @Federkun Could you please guide me how to check navigation in 2ndComponent as I am accessing it through props

Comment: what's the full output of `console.log('@@@@ route', { route, navigation }) ;`?

Comment: @Federkun it showing undefined

Comment: Could you show how you set up your navigation? Cuz possibly its nested and that's not a proper way to send params thru nested

Comment: @ßiansorÅ.Ålmerol sure. please check 
https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-night-l4v2y?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I suspect you aren't showing something critical from the real `EducationForm`, can you pass the code of that screen as well?